# UIAlertView conditional statmenst (if else??)

Tags: location, uialertview, if-statement

I'm new to coding and was wondering how I might be able to set a conditional statement for an alert message. So I have this so far:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES; 

NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                   @"Alert"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title message: @"I would like to use your location." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Allow" otherButtonTitles:@"Don't Allow", nil];
```

Basically I want to put an if else statement in.
if allow is selected, run showuserlocation... else NO.

How can I do that?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this yourself.  Just run your `showUserLocation` method.  The user will automatically be prompted to allow the app to access details about their current location, if they haven't already granted permission for your app.

The OS does this for you, as soon as your app attempts to access any location-based features.